# How to enable http/2 on an embedded Jetty 10?

Tags: java, embedded, jetty, http2

I try to enable http/2 on my Jetty 10.0.11 without luck. I use the follow code to create the ServerConnector:

```java
HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
httpConfig.setSendServerVersion( false );
httpConfig.setSendXPoweredBy( false );
HttpConnectionFactory http1 = new HttpConnectionFactory( httpConfig );

httpConfig.addCustomizer( new SecureRequestCustomizer( false ) ); // for https://localhost

SslContextFactory.Server sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory.Server();
// ... load the certificate
sslContextFactory.setCipherComparator( HTTP2Cipher.COMPARATOR );

Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader( getClass().getClassLoader() ); // for service worker
//HTTP2CServerConnectionFactory http2 = new HTTP2CServerConnectionFactory( httpConfig );
HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory http2 = new HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory( httpConfig );
ALPNServerConnectionFactory alpn = new ALPNServerConnectionFactory();
alpn.setDefaultProtocol( http1.getProtocol() );
SslConnectionFactory ssl = new SslConnectionFactory( sslContextFactory, alpn.getProtocol() );

ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector( this, acceptors, selectors, ssl, alpn, http2, http1 );

connector.setReuseAddress( false );
connector.setPort( port );
connector.setAcceptQueueSize( MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS.get().intValue() );
```

I have add the follow additional libraries for http/2:

- org.eclipse.jetty.http2:http2-server
- org.eclipse.jetty.http2:http2-common
- org.eclipse.jetty.http2:http2-hpack
- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-alpn-server
- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-alpn-java-server

---

If I try it with `https://localhost` the browser (Chrome) is using ever http/1.1.

- Does http/2 does not work with localhost?
- Does I need to add more libraries? Which?
- What is wrong on my code?
- Must I change some things on my servlets?

Comment: Use a proper hostname if you are testing https (SSL/TLS).  Chrome has special behavior for localhost, and ip addresses that will get in your way (done due to security concerns).  Not to mention that Java itself (on your server side) will also have similar restrictions for using localhost or ip addresses with TLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to re-wrap the `ConnectionFactory`s using `AbstractConnectionFactory.getFactories(...)`.

See [this section](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-11/programming-guide/index.html#pg-server-http-connector-protocol-http2-tls) of the documentation to setup HTTP/2 over TLS.

Make sure the KeyStore contains a valid certificate, even if it is self-signed.

You can also try to run (from your IDE) [this example](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-11.0.11/demos/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demos/Http2Server.java).

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem was:

wrong:

```
HTTP2CServerConnectionFactory http2 = new HTTP2CServerConnectionFactory( httpConfig );
```

right:

```
HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory http2 = new HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory( httpConfig );
```

Why ever any create such classes with such similar class name.

Comment: `http2` and `http2c` (also known as `h2c`) are different types of connections.